# Error when trying to create subscriptions in reporting services

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I am trying to set up reporting emailing SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services. When I click to save a subscription I recieve the following error:

An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for more details. (rsInternalError) Get Online Help The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'sysservers', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.

I was under the impression Reporting Services uses the role RSExecRole which is created during installation. Isn't mssqlsystemresources something that is not supposed to, and not easily touched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most because the user doesn't have permissions setup correctly. Can you check if RSEXECROLE doesn't have any DENY permissions and has correct permissions on the reportserver db.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/brian_kelley/archive/2007/11/6/3195.aspx

Based on the code in the above url, RSEXECROLE should have 323 rows on SQL Server 2005 SP3. Yours should match that.

Let me know what you find.

Comment: The report server is currently running SQL Server 2005 SP2. Are you running the Select statement above against master? When I do only 5 rows are returned. I should state that the RSExecRole did not exist so I created following these instructions:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281308.aspx

Comment: Not against master but against the ReportServer database.

Comment: Running it against the ReportServer db returned me 317 records and no, there where not any deny permissions

Comment: Setup a SQL Trace and do the above action. Figure out what was it trying to do and check the appropriate permissions are setup correctly.